# Preferred way to set SO timeout

Tags: httpclient, solrj, solrcloud, solr5

Are the following two do the same thing?

```
cloudSolrClient.getLbClient().getHttpClient().getParams()
                  .setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 50000);
```

and

```
cloudSolrClient.getLbClient().setSoTimeout(50000);
```

If they are, then which one is preferable to use (except the fact that the first one is deprecated)?